# Booting barely working, Windows 8 can't sleep/restart/shutdown without crashing

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, crash, lenovo-laptop

I'm getting some strange issues on a lenovo laptop, it goes like this

1. It barely boots, I get the lenovo BIOS logo and then sometimes I see the win8 loading dot-circle but then sometimes don't and the only way to actually but into the OS is by going into the BIOS menu, do nothing and then reboot. Still takes a lot of time despite having a SSD
2. When it boots it might freeze a bit after login into windows, but once inside it works normally and fast as always
3. ...but then if I put the computer to sleep it might do it well once but by the second time it just crashes. If instead I restart or shutdown it it crashes on the first go.

I already did a windows boot repair both automatic and through command line, fixed the bcd and every other run of the mill command, any ideas that don't involve a fresh reinstall from scratch?

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the SSD. Have you tried [upgrading the SSD firmware](http://www.storagereview.com/how_upgrade_ssd_firmware) to the latest version?

Comment: Also, please edit your question to provide more details like the model number of the Lenovo notebook, the SSD model and make, firmware version (if available)

Comment: When I experienced "crashes" during a shutdown it turns out I had a driver problem.  I used dianostic tools to determine which driver it was.

Comment: @Ramhound which tool?

Comment: @Ghost - The tool of your choice, there are dozens, and plenty of questions on this site and articles else where.

Comment: @Vinayak its a lenovo Y510p and the SSD is a small buffer type, 20GB I think but the thing is its not showing up on the diagnostics

Comment: I found [this thread](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/IdeaPad-Y-U-V-Z-and-P-series/Problems-with-Lenovo-Ideapad-y510p/m-p/1291863#M104122) where some people seem to have solved the problem by disabling ExpressCache, which is the equivalent of essentially disabling the SSD drive

Comment: If this were a hard drive, I would say it sounds like a slow spin up time. Not sure if there's a similar issue with SSDs